# Gnome keyring does not auto-unlock and nextcloud does not recognise it at all

Tags: linux, pam, gnome-keyring

I tried installing gnome-keyring so that I would not have to input my password for programs all the time when I start my computer.

I installed `gnome-keyring.x86_64` and `gnome-keyring-pam.x86_64` and then added

```
eval $(/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11,secrets,ssh)
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

to my `.xinitrc` and then I added

```
-auth optional pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

at the end of the `auth` section in `/etc/pam.d/login` and

```
-session optional pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

at the end of the `session` in `/etc/pam.d/login` section.
I then tried to reboot but nextcloud still asks for my password each time and says «No keychain service available».
Geary seems to recognise the keyring because when I start it the first time it asks me to unlock the keyring and after that does not ask again for passwords if I kill the geary process and start it again.

I am using fedora 27 with i3 and CDM (console display manager). Does anyone know how to make nextcloud recognise the keyring too and maybe how to make it auto-unlock on start?

Here is my full `.xinitrc`

```
#!/bin/sh

###########################

# Custom xinitrc goes here

systemctl --user import-environment DISPLAY
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -merge -I$HOME ~/.Xresources

# for gnome keyring
eval $(/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11,secrets,ssh)
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK

###########################



wm_bin="$1"
exec ${wm_bin}
```

and my `/etc/pam.d/login`

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       substack     system-auth
auth       include      postlogin
-auth optional pam_gnome_keyring.so
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_console.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      system-auth
session    include      postlogin
-session   optional     pam_ck_connector.so
-session optional pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen at the beginning of the line indicates it's a comment. Remove that and see if it works.

Comment: Welcome on board, I think your answer should include the proper Syntax, since you are trying to point out the error OP has committed.